# How Can I restrict the access to about page if the user is not logged in using next.js

Tags: redirect, next.js

How Can I restrict the access to about page if the user is not logged in using next.js

I need to restrict the access to the about page and some other pages in my project using node.js

node.js is not supporting the Redirect functionality in react, so can you please specify any alternative methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should handle that on client code, not server. For example:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

class PrivatePage extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps () {
    const loggedIn = getAuthData();
    // getAuthData is some method that returns you if user is logged in. You  
    // could take it from cookies/localStorage/redux store or fetch them.
    if (!loggedIn) {         
       Router.push('/login')
    }
  }
}
```